# HDMI Monitor works in Windows, but not Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, lenovo, hdmi, intel

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 5i with Intel iRISxe graphics with dual boot to Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04.
When I boot to Windows, I can use my external monitor, which is connected via HDMI. (no docking station).
But when I boot to Ubuntu, I get this:
[image: Settings>Displays]

It bothers me that my laptop's display is `Unknown`.
xrandr returns an error:

```
# xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 2560 x 1600, current 2560 x 1600, maximum 2560 x 1600
default connected primary 2560x1600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   2560x1600     93.00*
```

Further, a search of the lshw output does not find any reference to HDMI. (it does find VGA)
in ideapad-core-pci:

```
       *-display UNCLAIMED
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:601c000000-601cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

and in ideapad:

```
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 3
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=2560,1600
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the "unknown", especially since this is for the display that's working. Do you have an Ubuntu USB? It may be helpful from a diagnostic standpoint to boot a live session from USB to see if it works on a "clean" system.